# change classes jQuery is not removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I read all the other topics about this (by my oppinion) simple js commando.
It's about to change classes on elements in an unordered list.

But it's not working.

I'm working on my localhost and i have 3 files.
 - index.php
 - stylesheet-sidemenu.css
 - sidemenu.js

in the header of my index.php i have my redirects to the 2 files (the css and js files).

this is my html:`

```
<nav>   
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#"><span class="text">Afwijking</span> </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="text">Algemeen</span> </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="text">Frequentie</span> </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="text">Inleen</span> </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

here

this in my js in js/menu:

```
$('li').click(function(){

  $(this).addClass('active')
       .siblings()
       .removeClass('active');

});
```

And this is my css in css/sidemenu.css

```
li{
  height:50px; 
  position:relative;
  background: linear-gradient(#292929, #242424);
}
a {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  line-height:50px;
  color:#bbb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:12px;
  font-family: Calabri, helvetica, arial;
  padding-left:10%;
  border-left:5px solid transparent;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.active a{
  color: #fcb600;
  border-left:5px solid #fcb600;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
  outline:0;
}
li:not(.active):hover a{
  color: #eee;
  border-left: 5px solid #FCFCFC;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
}
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Nothing wrong with code shown...do the `<li>` exist when you run it?

Comment: If the script tag is in your `<head>`, then when it runs `$("li")` will match nothing. You could try `$(document).on("click", "li", ...)` instead.

Comment: @pointy  is this what you are meaning?
$(document).on("click", "li")
(function(){
 
  
  $(this).addClass('active')
       .siblings()
       .removeClass('active');
    
});

Comment: No, [the function should be the third argument to `.on()`.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Ah! thank you.
I was to focusesds on the code itself.
I was totaly forgotten to write

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it the head section. i thank you all for your knowledge.

Comment: Hi LGSon. i did as you asked. thank you for your well formed anwer.